# BASH - calculating MD5 recursively (not with MD5 DEEP)

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, md5sum

I have a function which calculate md5sum for each files in /bin.
However if I do "$(md5sum /bin/.* /bin/*) it will not do it recursively and will not calculate subfolders content.

I was thinking of a 'hacky' way of doing it. get the content of /bin with ls -la and then save it to a file. Then iterate over the file to calculate the hash. But this might be a bit heavy computation wise.

I know with md5deep its easy but if there another way of achieving this?

Comment: `find /bin -type f -exec md5sum {} \;` ? If you want the filenames to be sorted, you may consider using [this pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34325/sorting-the-output-of-find).

Comment: You can also simply use a loop: `for x in /bin/**/*; do md5sum "$x"; done`. This requires the `globstar` and `dotglob` options to be set, and you should can `nullglob` as well to handle case where the pattern matches no files (which, in this case, probably is not a concern).

Comment: Or just `md5sum /bin/**/*`.